# Creating Multiple pdf files with Texlipse

Tags: texlipse

I have been using Texlipse for a while now and like it.  The only issue that I have is that Texlipse only allows me to have a single Tex and PDF file in each project.  I was wondering if anyone had found a way to make Texlipse accept multiple Tex files and then output to multiple pdf files?  And assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You should enable a "Build partially" check-box in "Latex" menu.

Here is exempt from [TeXlipse FAQ](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/faq.php):

> **Why cannot I open an arbitrary TeX-file and compile it?**
>
> TeXlipse or more generally Eclipse needs a project where your files
>   are located. If you have many small files, e.g. letters, just create a
>   project called e.g. "misc." and add your small files to it. For more
>   details how to build these files, take a look at the next entry.
>
> **I have many self-contained LaTeX files in my project, but only my main
>   TeX file is build after save. How can I build the other files without
>   switching the main TeX file every time?**
>
> There is a nice feature in TeXlipse which you should use in this case: Partial building. If switched on, TeXlipse tries to build only
>   the file you are currently editing. It uses two different strategies
>   depending on the file type you are editing:
>
> 1. If the file is a "main" TeX file, it simply builds the file and move it to your output directory. When you use Preview Document after
>      that, this file will be shown.
> 2. If the file is not a self-contained TeX file, TeXlipse extracts the preamble of your main file and includes it together with the file
>      you are editing in a temporary file. This newly created file will be
>      build and shown if you preview it.

Comment: Hi, for some reason only "Set As Main File" and then building as normal, works. "Build Partially" does not do anything if the file is not set as main file. Is there a simpler way of compiling an individual tex file than setting it as main file every time? Thanks.

Comment: Can someone follow up with this?
I've enabled "partial building," but my independent (has begin/end document) .tex file is having a .pdf created. After every save, I see it build, but don't see any output. 
Re-reading that help blurb above, I'm not sure that it's relevant. 
Lastly, I don't have an "output directory," I can set an output file, but that's it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems not to be possible in Texlipse. You always have a single output PDF.

You can have many main files in the project though (e.g. one sided and two sided). To compile you should be able to simply open the tex file in TexWorks and run it.